# Detect manipulation of native browser object

Tags: javascript, security

Addons such as grease-monkey can modify the native javascript object handles before a webpage's scripts can get a handle on the original object.

This can allow great user-script functionality, but may also be unwanted by the website provider. Thus the javascript environment can be viewed as adversarial.

Below is an example of what I believe to be an undetectable change to the native object handles that could take place before loading the website's scripts

```
//closure to prevent variable leaks
(function(){

//malicious action (sudo detectable in this case)
var alertCopy=alert;
alert=function(a){alertCopy("Lol. You wanted to alert:"+a)};

//the cover-up
var toStringCopy=Function.prototype.toString;
Function.prototype.toString=function(){
   var subject=this;
   if(subject===alert){
       subject=alertCopy;
   }else if(subject===Function.prototype.toString){
       subject=toStringCopy;
   }
   return toStringCopy.call(subject);
}
})();
```

And a test in Chrome:

```
alert('hi');//alerted 'hi'
undefined
alert.toString();
"function alert() { [native code] }"
alert.toString.toString();
"function toString() { [native code] }"
    //closure to prevent variable leaks
    (function(){

    //malicious action (sudo detectable in this case)
    var alertCopy=alert;
    alert=function(a){alertCopy("Lol. You wanted to alert:"+a)};

    //the cover-up
    var toStringCopy=Function.prototype.toString;
    Function.prototype.toString=function(){
       var subject=this;
       if(subject===alert){
           subject=alertCopy;
       }else if(subject===Function.prototype.toString){
           subject=toStringCopy;
       }
       return toStringCopy.call(subject);
    }
    })();
undefined
alert('hi');//alerted 'Lol. You wanted to alert:hi'
undefined
alert.toString();
"function alert() { [native code] }"
alert.toString.toString();
"function toString() { [native code] }"
```

So if something like this has been set up before the page can load, is there any way to detect these modifications?

Note that the server will still consider all communications from the client hostile, this is just for the client code to attempt to detect if its environment has been modified prior to execution so that it may act accordingly.

related: [How to get the original native browser objects, if they have changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355631/how-to-get-the-original-native-browser-objects-if-they-have-changed)

Comment: How would your code act accordingly?

Comment: Well, the use case I was thinking about was for an online testing website, so any environment changes would be added to a suspicious activity list that may indicate that the user was attempting to cheat, in which case it may trigger the execution of dynamically loaded sniffing code to investigate further. Similar to google's anti-bot code.

Comment: imo suspicious activity should be registered by the server side.

Comment: Yep, the environmental change report would be sent server-side, along with other suspicious activity, and if the server decides to do so, it will load additional sniffing code to be executed client-side whose results would also be reported back. Anything unexpected coming back from the sniff (including no response) would result in a ban/cheating report.

Comment: receiving no suspicious activity reports would also probably trigger a sniff, as there should be some false positives coming to the server, during "normal" use. while this in no way prevents tampering the client software, it should make it harder to go undetected.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. You're running your code in an environment you don't control. There's no way to be sure that your detection script is going to function properly.

For example, if I can control the environment, I can edit your script prior to running it. So if you have a magic `isNative(fn)` function that somehow detects modifications to the core, the environment could simply replace it with `function isNative(fn) { return true; }`...

This is one reason that [JavaScript Cryptography Is Bad](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)...

In short, do anything sensitive on the server side. Don't trust what the client computes.

Comment: What add-on/ browser lets you pragmatically modify (or even read) javascript source code before it's executed? This would be a very helpful tool.

Comment: It was more of a generic comment around the level of trust you can place in an environment you can't control.

Comment: Ahh.. Well I think it makes a large difference. If I can send a skilled paratrooper into a warzone, I might be able to accomplish something. However, if my paratrooper can be brainwashed before even hitting the ground, then indeed all hope is lost.